# Set significant digits in summary_rows() using gt package

Tags: r, gt

I'm trying to set number of significant digits inside the summary_rows() function to format mean and sd outputs as following:

```
library(gt)
library(tidyverse)

iris %>%
 gt(groupname_col = "Species") %>%
 summary_rows(
    groups = TRUE,
    columns = c(Sepal.Length:Petal.Width),
    fns = list(
      Mean = "mean",
      SD = "sd"),
    formatter = fmt_number(n_sigfig = 1))
```

But returns that argument "data" is missing.
Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to the documentation are the '...' for additional parameters of the formatter:

```
library(gt)
library(tidyverse)

   iris %>%
      gt(groupname_col = "Species") %>%
      summary_rows(
        groups = TRUE,
        columns = c(Sepal.Length:Petal.Width),
        fns = list(
          Mean = "mean",
          SD = "sd"),
        formatter = fmt_number, n_sigfig = 1)
```